# UITableView Flickering with UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I have a`UITableView`  with`UIRefreshControl`  defined inside the `viewDidLoad:` method of a`UIViewController`  as below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshMessages) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    tableViewController.tableView = self.messagesTableView;
    tableViewController.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;  
}

- (void)refreshMessages {
    //load data items
    if ([self.refreshControl isRefreshing]) {
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }

    [self.messagesTableView reloadData];
}
```

I use self sizing cell to update the cell data. On re-loading the data the`UITableView`  flickers. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: So do you have a 'UIViewController' or a 'UITableViewController'?  Where do you present the 'tableViewController' object you initialize in viewDidLoad? You should provide more information, this would help

Comment: just a shot in the dark but did you try [tableView beginUpdates/endUpdates] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the issue is using estimatedHeight & UITableViewAutomaticDimension along with uitableview's reloadData. This has been reported [here](http://openradar.appspot.com/20105573)

The delay would work but its still not the right way to achieve it unless you want a hackish work around.

Answer (score 12):

I got the same issue today and I managed to solve the problem using CATransaction, here is a code snippet in Swift, executed within a UITableViewController :

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { () -> Void in
    /*wait for endRefreshing animation to complete 
          before reloadData so table view does not flicker to top 
          then continue endRefreshing animation */

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

self.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()
CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: I had a similar flickering problem that was happening when, while near the bottom of the tableview, new rows were added at the bottom *and* rows were deleted from the top.  This was solved by using `CATransaction.begin() ... CATransaction.setDisableActions(true) ... tableView.beginUpdates() ... do the updates ... tableView.endUpdate() ... CATransaction.commit()`

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are calling -reloadData and -endRefreshing together. Both want to update the view. You need to separate them a bit.

One of these options will work, depending on where you want to see the cells update:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.refreshControl performSelector:@selector(endRefreshing) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

[self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
[self.tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

Probably you need less delay with the first option. Even 0.0 seconds seemed to work in your example code. That's enough to get the -endRefreshing animation on the next screen refresh.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift**

You may want to use

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

in your ViewController in order to have correct UIRefreshControl animation.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)refreshMessages{
    self.messages = [NSMutableArray new];
    [self loadData];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 0):

May be calling `reloadData` and `endRefreshing` could have caused the flicker to take place so what i did was modified your code a bit and removed the dispatch block which cleared off the flick

```
- (void)refreshMessages{

self.messages = [NSMutableArray new];
[self loadData];
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.refreshControl performSelector:@selector(endRefreshing) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];


//    double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
//    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t) (delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
//    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
//        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
//    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
[self.messagesTableView beginUpdates];
[self.messagesTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0/*target section*/]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.messagesTableView endUpdates];
```

instead of:

```
[self.messagesTableView reloadData];
```